# python execution order in single method

Tags: python, execution

I was using nosetest to test method coverage. I found that later lines of code are covered even if they are not executed. Could anyone provide some insight on why this happens? I was thinking that python was doing some optimization by doing out of order execution.

```py
def highest_affinity(site_list, user_list, time_list):
    # Returned string pair should be ordered by dictionary order
    # I.e., if the highest affinity pair is "foo" and "bar"
    # return ("bar", "foo").

    return ''

    user_history = {}

    for site, user in zip(site_list, site_list):
        if user not in user_history:
            user_history[user] = set()

        user_history[user].add(site)

    affinities = {}
    for user, history in user_history.items():
        history = list(history)
        history.sort()
        for i, site1 in enumerate(history):
            for site2 in history[i+1:]:
                pair = (site1, site2)
                if pair not in affinities:
                    affinities[pair] = 0
                affinities[pair] += 1

    print(user_history)
    print(user_history)
    print(user_history)
    print(user_history)
    print(user_history)
    print(user_history)
    print(user_history)
    print(user_history)
    print(user_history)
    print(user_history)
    print(user_history)
    print(user_history)
    return max(affinities, key=affinities.get)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post an image showing the code coverage from Nose? It will be easier to see what is and isn't covered

Comment: @C_Z_ Sure, of course. Image attached